# Executing a function on buffer enter and on buffer leave events?

Tags: buffers, autocmd, filetype

I would like to execute a certain function every time I leave a buffer associated with **C++**, and another function every time I enter a **C++** buffer. I came up with this so far:

```
" Buffer Leave
augroup myBufferLeave
    autocmd BufLeave *.cpp,*.c,*.h call s:ExecuteLeave()
augroup END

" Buffer Enter
augroup myBufferEnter
    autocmd BufEnter *.cpp,*.c,*.h call s:ExecuteEnter()
augroup END
```

Another alternative is to hook into the global `BufEnter` event and set a buffer variable or check the current `&ft` and execute the appropriate function:

```
autocmd BufEnter * if &ft = 'cpp' |
    \ call s:ExecuteEnter() |
    \ endif

autocmd BufLeave * if &ft = 'cpp' |
    \ call s:ExecuteLeave() |
    \ endif
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Ideally, without tapping into the `*` global buffer events. Ideally, I would like to use something like this:

```
 autocmd BufLeave cpp call s:ExecuteLeave()
 autocmd BufEnter cpp call s:ExecuteEnter()
```

Is there a way to pack the `*.cpp,*.c,*.h` condition into one single definition such as `cpp`? The `cpp` definition is a `FileType`, but file-types are not triggered on `BufEnter` and `BufLeave`. If one needs to add another file extension, such as `*.CXX` for example, the list will become bloated eventually `*.cpp,*.c,*.h, *.CXX, *.C,` and a bit hard to maintain.

Comment: Possible [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly are you trying to do? Have buffer specific mappings (See `:h :map-local`), buffer commands (See `:h :command-buffer`), or buffer local settings (See `:h setlocal`)?

Comment: I would like to be able to come up with a buffer enter/leave event that is not depending on long file extension lists. Ideally, dealing with the file extensions problem in a 'ftdetect' script, and put ambiguous file extensions such  as '*.h, *.C, *.CXX' into a 'cpp' file type, so we keep adding to these in order to include new extensions into the defined file type and on the 'BufEnter' and 'BufLeave' side we just use the FileType tag, such as 'cpp' instead of a long list of constantly growing extensions.

Comment: I understand what the kind of `autocmd` pattern you are trying to craft (Spoiler: your `autocmd * if &ft` method is the correct way to do this). My question to you is what are your `ExecuteEnter()`/`ExecuteLeave()` supposed to be doing? More than likely you are trying to add buffer specific mappings/commands/settings, of which there are better ways methods.

Comment: I would like to set an option, set completeopt-=preview when entering C++ or C buffers and set completeopt+=preview when leaving C++ or C buffers. But nowadays, the C/C++ files may have a very rich variety of extensions, writing down all of these seems too laborious and not very smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `completeopt` is a global option, you are correct in that you need a way to toggle the `preview` setting. I suggest you do this via the `BufEnter` autocmd with a `*` as the pattern.

```
augroup TogglePreview
  autocmd!
  autocmd Filetype,BufEnter * execute 'set completeopt'.(&ft == 'cpp' ? '+' : '-').'=preview'
augroup END
```

The idea is that the autocmd uses `'filetype'` upon entering a new buffer or settings the buffer's `'filetype'` to decide to turn on/off the `preview` option.

You may want to consider using `:pclose` to close the preview window as well.

For more help see:

```
:h :au
:h BufEnter
:h 'completeopt'
:h :exe
:h :pclose
```

Comment: Cool. It seems like this has to be an '*' event. Why would you prefer WinEnter over BufEnter? Also, why do we need the 'FileType' in there? Is not WinEnter (or BuffEnter) enough? Thanks.

Comment: Using `BufEnter` is probably better (I have changed the post). The reason I use `FileType` event is in case you a buffer's `'filetype'` changes.